# How to fix overlaying polygons in US map?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

The below gives overlaying polygons, how to fix it?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = map_data("state")) + geom_polygon(aes(long, lat, group = region), 
  color = "red", fill = "red", alpha = 0.2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud use `group = group` as an argument of `geom_poly` please see as below:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = map_data("state")) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(long, lat, group = group), 
               color = "red", fill = "red", alpha = 0.2)
```

Output:
[image: map]